# Batch reduce bitrate and size of mp3 audio files with ffmpeg

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, mp3, bitrate

I was looking for a way to batch reduce mp3 bitrate on my sizable collection of mp3 files. It was surprising difficult given that this must be a super common thing to want to do.

In fact, there are dozens, maybe hundreds, of posts from people asking how to do it, and dozens of utilities available for varying amounts of money that claim to do just that. Looking around and trying some of the free software, I was surprised that none made the task of batch converting/adjustment easy.

If I wanted to convert a single file, I'm told this is a decent way to do it:

```
ffmpeg -y -loglevel "error" -i "my_music_file.mp3" -acodec libmp3lame  -ab $BITRATE "my_music_file_new.mp3"
```

(Though I'd prefer if the file was changed in place and resulted in the same name.)

I need a simple bash script using ffmpeg that will recursively go through my music directory and change the bitrate of my mp3 files.

Comment: You can provide answers to your own questions, so consider re-writing your question as a typical question and provide your solution as an answer to the question. That also allows people to know that the question has an accepted solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It took a bit of fiddling to get the right ffmpeg and find options, but this should do it.

```
#!/bin/bash
MUSIC="FULL PATH TO YOUR MUSIC FOLDER"
BITRATE=160k
find "${MUSIC}" -name "*.mp3" \
  -execdir echo "{}" \; \
  -exec mv "{}" "{}.mp3" \; \
  -exec ffmpeg -y -loglevel "error" -i "{}.mp3" -acodec libmp3lame  -ab $BITRATE "{}" \; \
  -exec rm "{}.mp3" \;
```

Because ffmpeg can't output to the same input file without nuking it, the script first renames the file, builds a new one at your chosen bitrate, then removes the old file.

I'm sure that many people will have suggested improvements here. I certainly welcome ways to make the script more readable.

Comment: it's probably better to use ogg, in my humble opinion. and here's to more readable scripts: https://gist.github.com/protrolium/e0dbd4bb0f1a396fcb55

Comment: just figured a much better way to compress. had a 320kbps mp3 16mb big. this turned it into less than 0.7mb and i couldn't hear a single difference. trying with 8k, though, broke it (not worth the 0.3mb saved). so 16 is currently ideal! `ffmpeg -i file.mp3 -b:a 8k -acodec libopus file.ogg`. opus seem to be far superior than the default vorbis. but it's also less used, so less compatible even with some new apps.